# Why is FLT_MIN equal to zero?

Tags: c, floating-point, numeric-limits

`limits.h` specifies limits for non-floating point math types, e.g. `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX`. These values are the most negative and most positive values that you can represent using an int.

In `float.h`, there are definitions for `FLT_MIN` and `FLT_MAX`. If you do the following:

```
NSLog(@"%f %f", FLT_MIN, FLT_MAX);
```

You get the following output:

```
FLT_MIN = 0.000000, FLT_MAX = 340282346638528859811704183484516925440.000000
```

`FLT_MAX` is equal to a really large number, as you would expect, but why does `FLT_MIN` equal zero instead of a really large negative number?

Comment: `FLT_MIN` on my machine is `1.17549435e-38F`.

Comment: How are you checking the value? Looking in a header file somewhere? Using a printf? (If you're using printf, you're not using "%f", are you? You'll want "%e" to get exponential notation.)

Comment: I've updated both the Q and A to clarify the %f printf issue.

Comment: Try `printf("FLT_MIN: %.100f\n", FLT_MIN);`

Comment: @SlippD.Thompson Try reading the existing answers ;-)

Comment: @NickForge Yes, exactly.  It applied to both answers but contained additional information that neither did, so I put it here.  Didn't seem to warrant an additional answer either.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

It's not actually zero, but it might look like zero if you inspect it using `printf` or `NSLog` by using `%f`.
According to `float.h` (at least in Mac OS X 10.6.2), `FLT_MIN` is described as:

```
/* Minimum normalized positive floating-point number, b**(emin - 1).  */
```

Note the *positive* in that sentence: `FLT_MIN` refers to the minimum (normalized) number *greater than zero*. (There are much smaller non-normalized numbers).

If you want the minimum floating point number (including negative numbers), use `-FLT_MAX`.

Comment: This doesn't even seem like an answer to me - I thought your question was why it's zero instead of something very small and positive.

Comment: It could be argued that 0 isn't strictly positive, and that the value should be 1.4e-45 or whatever the value right before underflow is.

Comment: I've updated the answer - you're absolutely correct about it not being zero. I'll update the question to reflect that it _looks like_ zero when you do a printf, not that it's actually zero.

Comment: The text in the comment, "Minimum normalized positive floating-point number, b**(emin - 1)," is straight out of the C standard, and is valid for any C implementation (see ISO/IEC 9899:TC2 5.2.4.2.2/11).

Comment: @Nick: It doesn't look like zero if you use exponential notation.

Comment: @Jefromi: You're right, but I'm leaving the answer how it is, since I suspect more people will find the question helpful be saying it looks like zero.

Comment: `FLT_MIN` refers to the minimum **normalized** positive float. The minimum positive float is a denormalized number, namely 2^(-149) ≈ 1.4013e-45.

Comment: "want the minimum floating point number (including negative numbers), use -FLT_MAX" --> When `INF` exists as a `float`, `-INF` is less than `-FLT_MAX`.  Better wording here would be "minimum _finite_ floating point number".

Answer (score 16):

The '%f' format prints 6 decimal places in fixed format.  Since FLT_MIN is a lot smaller, it looks like zero in fixed point.  If you use '%e' or '%g' format, you'd get a better formatted answer.  Similarly with the FLT_MAX.

```
#include <float.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    printf("MIN = %f, MAX = %f\n", FLT_MIN, FLT_MAX);
    printf("MIN = %e, MAX = %e\n", FLT_MIN, FLT_MAX);
    return(0);
}


MIN = 0.000000, MAX = 340282346638528859811704183484516925440.000000
MIN = 1.175494e-38, MAX = 3.402823e+38
```

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you will try to print the value of FLT_MIN from standard header file 
float.h ,you will get 0.000000(as you are seeing in your output screen).
That is not actually a error. You are getting this result because the format specifier %f.
Generally %f print 6 digits after the decimal point but in this case the signed negative value is so small that you need to print significant amount of digits after the decimal point.

I have used %.54f(machine dependent) to get the desired-
result(0.000000000000000000000000000000000000011754943508222875 for my system).

//Check this on your system

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<float.h>
int main()
{
    printf("Minimum signed float %.55f\n",FLT_MIN);
    printf("Minimum signed float %e\n",FLT_MIN);
    return 0;
}
```

//Output :-

// Minimum signed float 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000117549435082228750

// Minimum signed float 1.175494e-038

I think now it's clear to you why you are getting 0.000000 for CHAR_MIN and how
to get the correct result with the same format specifier.Though  you can use %e for better formatted result.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is `FLT_MIN` equal to zero?

It is not equal to zero.  It appears as `0.000000` due to using `"%f"` which prints 6 decimal digits after the decimal place `.`.
`FLT_MIN` often has a value about 1.17549435e-38.

---

**Reference**

Although this question has been answered as to why, I thought I would post  the *exact* values for `FLT_TRUE_MIN, FLT_MIN, FLT_MAX` as well as their nearest `float` neighbors when `float` is [binary32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format).

```
// Approximate value, exact value
Before, FLT_TRUE_MIN, after
 0.00000000e+00 0.0
 1.40129846e-45 0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000140129846432481707092372958328991613128026194187651577175706828388979108268586060148663818836212158203125
 2.80259693e-45 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000028025969286496341418474591665798322625605238837530315435141365677795821653717212029732763767242431640625
Before, FLT_MIN, after
 1.17549421e-38 0.00000000000000000000000000000000000001175494210692441075487029444849287348827052428745893333857174530571588870475618904265502351336181163787841796875
 1.17549435e-38 0.000000000000000000000000000000000000011754943508222875079687365372222456778186655567720875215087517062784172594547271728515625
 1.17549449e-38 0.00000000000000000000000000000000000001175494490952133940450443629595204006810278684798281709160328881985245648433835441437622648663818836212158203125
Before, FLT_MAX, after
 3.40282326e+38 340282326356119256160033759537265639424.0
 3.40282347e+38 340282346638528859811704183484516925440.0
            inf inf
```