# Data type promotion or demotion in C

Tags: c, types

Which of these are data type promotion and demotion :

```
char ch = 'C';
int i = 65;
float fl = 2.2;

ch = ch + 1;
i = fl + 2 * ch;
fl = 2.0 * ch + i;
ch = 5212205.17;
```

Am I correct if i say :

Promotion :

> - `i = fl + 2 * ch;`
> - `fl = 2 * ch + i;`

demotion :

```
  ch = 5211205.17;
```

not sure if

```
  ch = ch + 1;
```

Is also demotion.. please help :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
char ch = 'C';
```

The literal `'C'` is of type **int** and *demoted* to type **char** (conversion to the left operator during assignment).

```
float fl = 2.2;
```

The literal `2.2` is of type **double** and *demoted* to type **float** (conversion to the left operator during assignment).

```
ch = ch + 1;
```

The variable ch is of type **char** and *promoted* to type **int** (integer promotions).

The result of the addition `ch + 1` is of type **int** and *demoted* to type **char** (conversion to the left operator during assignment).

```
i = fl + 2 * ch;
```

The variable ch is of type **char** and *promoted* to type **int** (integer promotions).

The result of `2 * ch` is of type **int** and *promoted* to type **float** (balancing).

The result of `fl + 2 * ch` is of type **float**. The float is *demoted* to an **int** (conversion to the left operator during assignment). This is a dangerous conversion because of loss of precision and a good compiler should give a warning for attempting to store a float inside an int without an explicit cast.

```
fl = 2.0 * ch + i;
```

The variable ch is of type **char** and first *promoted* to type **int** (integer promotions) and then *promoted* to type **double** (balancing).

The result of `2.0 * ch` is of type **double**.

The result of `2.0 * ch + i` is of type **double** and *demoted* to type **float** (conversion to the left operator during assignment).

```
ch = 5212205.17;
```

The literal 5212205.17 is of type **double** and *demoted* to type **char** (conversion to the left operator during assignment). This is a dangerous conversion and possibly also undefined behavior, since the signedness of char is implementation-defined, and also the number cannot fit inside a char.

Attempting to store a signed floating point number inside a type that cannot represent it (such as an unsigned int) is undefined behavior, i.e. a severe bug.

Comment: Thanks for explaining each and every one ! I understood them better thanks to you :)

Comment: As you can hopefully tell from this, it is very important to understand what types your program is actually using. Constant literals have types as well as any variable, and they are subject to the same conversion rules. Which literal syntax you use determines the type, and thereby the outcome of the program. `1`, `1.0`, `1.0f`, `1U`, `1L`, `1UL`, `'1'`, `"1"` and so on, are all various different types. Programmers who don't understand this or don't understand implicit promotions _will_ write hundreds of hard-to-find bugs. It is not easy to learn, even veteran programmers struggle with this.

Comment: Nice complete explanation.  Idea to add: `long` to `float` promotion may lose precision.  As in a 4-byte `long` 2147483647 to [binary32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary32)  `float` which becomes 2147483648.0

Comment: @chux Whether or not you lose precision does of course depend on the nature of the built-in types. What float format is use, how large is a long etc. Which in turn makes one realize that such code is unlikely to be portable, unless you are really, really careful.

Comment: @lundin Thanks for the thorough answer. Could you also explain signed<->unsigned demotion/promotion ?

Comment: @AlexeyPolonsky Not sure what you mean, maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17312545/type-conversion-unsigned-to-signed-int-char)?

Comment: @Lundin Thanks, actually I was hoping for something more detailed, like a set of rules that includes the fact that {int a=-5; a>>=8} would fill MSB of "a" with 1's, but {unsigned int a=-5; a>>=8} would fill MSB of "a" with zeros.

Comment: @AlexeyPolonsky Your particular example has nothing to do with type promotion. The shift operators follow specific rules. And there are actually no guarantees of what will happen when you right shift a negative integer: it is implementation-defined behavior. Performing shift operations on signed and/or negative integers is a bug/doesn't make any sense, in 99% of the cases.

Comment: @Lundin Bingo ! Undefined behavior is a good answer. I just looked in C ISO2011 standard and it brings exactly this case as an example : "An example of implementation-defined behavior is the propagation of the high-order bit when a signed integer is shifted right."

Comment: @AlexeyPolonsky Please note that _right shift of a negative number is implementation-defined behavior_, it could perform arithmetic shift (fill up with the sign bit) or logical shift (fill up with zeroes) or something else. But _left shift of a negative number is undefined behavior_, you shift data into the sign bit and then anything can happen.

Comment: Can someone help explain why `2 * ch` is promoted to type float (balancing)?  Shouldn't `ch` be promoted to `int` then multiplied with `2`; the outcome of which is still `int`?

Comment: @AndyJ Indeed, both operands `2` and `ch` are promoted to `int` if needed. The promotion of the result of `2 * ch` to `float` takes place when a float operand is involved here: `fl + 2 * ch`. The whole expression is equivalent to `i = (int) (fl + (float)(2 * (int)ch));`. See [the usual arithmetic conversions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3t4w2bkb.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Lundin.  I understand a lot clearer now.  But I'm a little discombobulated by your use of the word "Balanced".  I googled it for the context of this topic and google yielded nothing.

Comment: @AndyJ "Balancing" is an informal term for "the usual arithmetic conversions". Implicit type promotion is the general term.

Answer (score 1):

In `ch = ch+1;` Here 1 is an integer so `ch` is promoted to integer and add to 1 then result is demoted to character and stored in ch.

Comment: So it's both demotion and promotion ? .. or just demotion? thanks!

Comment: @user3227610 first promotion, and finally demotion.

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of such a concept as "data type demotion" in C programming.

"Promotion" is usually used to denote the fact of converting a "small" type to a bigger type which is native on the platform for which the program is compiled.

For instance, on an x86, gcc will promote an 8-bit char to a 32-bit integer, because the ALU of an x86 processor works on 32-bit words for integers.

To come back to your question, either it's about implicit type conversion, or we miss some context to be able to say which variable will be promoted.

Disclaimer : it looks like you may be preparing for an exam, in which case you should probably stick to your teacher's conventions. Maybe he's calling implicit conversion of an integer or a floating point type to a larger integer respectively floating point type a promotion, the truncation of the fractional part as a demotion, or an integer overflow as a demotion as well.

Comment: There is indeed a formal definition of "promotion" in the C standard, but no such formal definition of "demotion". The C standard does speak of type demotion in non-normative text however. What we informally call demotion, would formally be called _conversion during simple assignment_ or some such, it is specified in C11 6.5.16.1.