# Why does the C++ bitwise AND operator behave like this with different-sized operands?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

Curious about whether type size is a factor when removing bits using one's compliment `operator ~`, I ended up with this curious result:

```
uint64_t x = 0xccccccccccccccccUL;
uint8_t y = 10;
auto z = ~y; // Debugger calls z an 'int' with value of 0xfffffff5
x &= z;
// x is now the correct value: 0xccccccccccccccc4
```

How can `operator &` return a value greater than either of the operands?

The following example confuses me further, because it seems like the same logic but yields a different result:

```
uint64_t x = 0xccccccccccccccccUL;
x &= 0xfffffff5;
// Now x is 0x00000000ccccccc4
```

What explains this? Is it actually safe to use `x &= ~y` to remove bits regardless of type size / sign?

Comment: _"// Debugger calls z an 'int' with value of 0xfffffffa"_ the value can't be `0xfffffffa`, it must be `0xfffffff5`, please clarify

Comment: `z` is signed, and when coerced to the width of `x`, it is sign-extended. Don't use signed numbers for bit manipulation.

Comment: This ends up coming down usual arithmetic conversions and integral promotions examples [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22702091/1708801) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23994293/1708801)

Comment: Using `auto z` is a poor idea here. Use `uint8_t z`  instead or maybe `uint64_t z`, it depends on what you want to achieve.

Comment: Still not qute correct: `0xccccccccccccccc4` ->  `0xccccccccccccccc5` etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing two widening operations there. The first is your `~`, which (like any arithmetic operator) performs standard "integer promotion". In this case, since all values of the source type (`uint8_t`) can fit in an `int`, that's the promotion performed. So as you've noticed, `z` is deduced to have type `int`.

The second widening operation is the `&=`, which in this case is equivalent to `x = x & z`. `uint64_t` won't fit in an `int` or in an `unsigned int`, nor even in an `int64_t`, but both `uint64_t` and `int` will fit in a `uint64_t`, so that's the chosen type. Widening a (signed) `int` involves sign extension, so that's where the extra bits come from.

To answer your final question, *no*, it is not safe to use `x &= ~y` to clear a bit if `y` has a signed type or is narrower than `x`. For more about that, see [this article](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/EXP14-C.+Beware+of+integer+promotion+when+performing+bitwise+operations+on+integer+types+smaller+than+int), but the bottom line is, make sure to convert `~var` to the expected *unsigned* type if there may be a widening promotion happening. If you had used `uint8_t` instead of `auto` for `z`, you wouldn't have run into this issue.

Comment: Aha it's the sign extension that was the root of my confusion.