# Why are integer types promoted during addition in C?

Tags: c, integer-promotion

So we had a field issue, and after days of debugging, narrowed down the problem to this particular bit of code, where the processing in a while loop wasn't happening :

```
// heavily redacted code
// numberA and numberB are both of uint16_t
// Important stuff happens in that while loop

while ( numberA + 1 == numberB )
{
    // some processing
}
```

This had run fine, until we hit the uint16 limit of 65535. Another bunch of print statements later, we discovered that `numberA + 1` had a value of `65536`, while `numberB` wrapped back to `0`. This failed the check and no processing was done.

This got me curious, so I put together a quick C program (compiled with GCC 4.9.2) to check this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{

    uint16_t numberA, numberB;
    numberA = 65535;
    numberB = numberA + 1;

    uint32_t numberC, numberD;
    numberC = 4294967295;
    numberD = numberC + 1;

    printf("numberA = %d\n", numberA + 1);
    printf("numberB = %d\n", numberB);

    printf("numberC = %d\n", numberC + 1);
    printf("numberD = %d\n", numberD);

    return 0;
}
```

And the result was :

```
numberA = 65536
numberB = 0
numberC = 0
numberD = 0
```

So it appears that the result of `numberA + 1` was promoted to uint32_t. Is this intended by the C language ? Or is this some compiler / hardware oddity?

Comment: FYI, printing `uint32_t` and `uint16_t` using the `%d` format specifier invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant On the OP's platform, printing an `uint16_t` with `%d` does not cause UB for the same reason that `numberA + 1` is not equal to `numberB`. In all likelihood, the OP's `uint32_t` is defined as `int` and you are correct about undefined behavior for the last two `printf` calls. If `int` were 64-bit wide, the last two `printf` calls would be defined.

Comment: @MattMcNabb I'm not saying that the OP might have defined `uint32_t` as something or other. I am saying that the OP's platform defines it to either `unsigned int` or something narrower than `unsigned int`.

Comment: @PascalCuoq you said "the OP's uint32_t is defined as int" , was that a typo

Comment: @MattMcNabb Arg, yes, and it is just too late to edit now.

Comment: Kind of a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17312545/type-conversion-unsigned-to-signed-int-char. I think we might need to create a FAQ post regarding implicit type promotions.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant This is very similar if not a duplicate of [Why must a short be converted to an int before arithmetic operations in C and C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24371868/1708801)

Comment: I guess the biggest difference (compared to the dups) is that the integer promotion happened *inside* a while loop check where `numberA + 1` was never explicitly assigned to any variable. This made it much harder to find. Beyond that, integer promotion is what it is ...

Comment: Thanks to all the contributors! I guess I learnt something new today =)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> So it appears that the result of `numberA + 1` was promoted to `uint32_t`

The **operands** of the addition were promoted to `int` before the addition took place, and the result of the addition is of the same type as the effective operands (`int`).

Indeed, if `int` is 32-bit wide on your compilation platform (meaning that the type that represents `uint16_t` has lower “conversion rank” than `int`), then `numberA + 1` is computed as an `int` addition between `1` and a promoted `numberA` as part of the integer promotion rules, 6.3.1.1:2 in the C11 standard:

> The following may be used in an expression wherever an int or unsigned int may be used: […] An object or expression with an integer type (other than int or unsigned int) whose integer conversion rank is less than or equal to the rank of int and unsigned int.
>
> […]
>
> If an int can represent all values of the original type […], the value is converted to an int

In your case, `unsigned short` which is in all likelihood what `uint16_t` is defined as on your platform, has all its values representable as elements of `int`, so the `unsigned short` value `numberA` gets promoted to `int` when it occurs in an arithmetic operation.

Comment: To be picky, what you cite is the integer promotion rules, which are indeed part of the usual arithmetic conversions. But "the usual..." are not specified in 6.3.1.1, they are specified in 6.3.1.8. I propose that you change your answer to "...promoted numberA , which is promoted according to the integer promotion rules 6.3.1.1/2:". "The usual arithemtic" rather refers to the balancing between two operands of a binary operator, which doesn't apply in this case.

Comment: @Lundin Yes, I (and Matt McNabb) remembered integer promotions as being part of usual arithmetic conversions, but you are right. I removed the reference to them.

Comment: @mirabilos: The promotion to int only happens if FOO_MAX <= INT_MAX in the first place. uint_32t will not be promoted to int if the latter is 32-bit.

Answer (score 10):

For arithmetic operators such as `+`, the *usual arithmetic conversions* are applied.

For integers, the first step of those conversions is called the *integer promotions*, and this promotes any value of type smaller than `int` to be an `int`.

The other steps don't apply to your example so I shall omit them for conciseness.

In the expression `numberA + 1`,  the integer promotions are applied. `1` is already an `int` so it remains unchanged. `numberA` has type `uint16_t` which is narrower than `int` on your system, so `numberA` gets promoted to `int`.

The result of adding two `int`s is another `int`, and `65535 + 1` gives `65536` since you have 32-bit `int`s.

So your first `printf` outputs this result.

In the line:

```
numberB = numberA + 1;
```

the above logic still applies to the `+` operator, this is equivalent to:

```
numberB = 65536;
```

Since `numberB` has an unsigned type, `uint16_t` specifically, `65536` is reduced (mod 65536) which gives `0`.

Note that your last two `printf` statements cause undefined behaviour; you must use `%u` for printing `unsigned int`.  To cope with different sizes of `int`, you can use `"%" PRIu32` to get the format specifier for `uint32_t`.

Comment: +1 for telling me how I was wrong. Twice. I'll just leave the title as-is. Editing it would make your answer look weird.

Comment: %d is fine as long as the unsigned int value is in the range of int values.

Comment: @gnasher729 well that's arguable

Answer (score 4):

When the C language was being developed, it was desirable to minimize the number of kinds of arithmetic compilers had to deal with.  Thus, most math operators (e.g. addition) supported only int+int, long+long, and double+double.  While the language could have been simplified by omitting int+int (promoting everything to `long` instead), arithmetic on `long` values generally takes 2-4 times as much code as arithmetic on `int` values; since most programs are dominated by arithmetic on `int` types, that would have been very costly.  Promoting `float` to `double`, by contrast, will in many cases save code, because it means that only two functions are needed to support `float`: convert to `double`, and convert from `double`.  All other floating-point arithmetic operations need only support one floating-point type, and since floating-point math is often done by calling library routines the cost of calling a routine to add two `double` values is often the same as the cost to call a routine to add two `float` values.

Unfortunately, the C language became widespread on a variety of platforms before anyone really figured out what 0xFFFF + 1 should mean, and by that time there were already some compilers where the expression yielded 65536 and some where it yielded zero.  Consequently, writers of standards have endeavored to write them in a fashion that would allow compilers to keep on doing whatever they were doing, but which was rather unhelpful from the standpoint of anyone hoping to write portable code.  Thus, on platforms where `int` is 32 bits, 0xFFFF+1 will yield 65536, and on platforms where `int` is 16 bits, it will yield zero.  If on some platform `int` happened to be 17 bits, 0xFFFF+1 would authorize the compiler to negate the laws of time and causality [btw, I don't know if any 17-bit platforms, but there are some 32-bit platforms where `uint16_t x=0xFFFF; uint16_t y=x*x;` will cause the compiler to garble the behavior of code which *precedes* it].

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: @JamesPicone: I supposed I could have added an explicit statement that `uint16_t` is getting promoted because it's smaller than `int`, but that would leave open the question of whether such behavior was "intended by the C language".  Assuming the OP is asking about the intentions of the people who designed and documented the language, since the language *itself* isn't sentient, the best way to understand those people's intentions would be to look at that reasons the language was designed as it was.

Comment: "there are some 32-bit platforms where `uint16_t x=0xFFFF; uint16_t y=x*x;` will cause the compiler to garble the behavior of code which precedes it"

Do you have a source for this? Sounds standards-violating; I think arithmetic on *unsigned* integers has to be modulo 2^n.

Comment: @AlexRobbins: See https://godbolt.org/z/G8rvjbYsc for an example of gcc's creativity with integer promotions.  The fact that integer overflow would occur if n was 32770 or greater will result in a compiler assuming that q will always be 1, even though the result of the calculation that would overflow is completely ignored.  The authors of the Standard could never have anticipated such creativity, and thus saw no need to forbid it.

Answer (score 0):

Literal `1` in of `int`, i.e. in your case int32 type, so operations with int32 and int16 give results of int32.

To have result of `numberA + 1` statement as `uint16_t` try explicit type cast for `1`, e.g.: `numberA + (uint16_t)1`

Comment: Partly right, integer literals are of yup *`int`*, no matter the size of `int`.

Comment: The reason why the addition is between `int` operands is not that `1` has type `int`. The same thing would happen with `numberA + (char)1` or indeed with `numberA + (uint16_t)1`. The recommendation “try explicit type cast …” simply doesn't work. Try it.

Comment: `numberA + (uint16_t)1` is indeed nonsense and shows that you don't understand how the type promotions work. Not sure why this received up-votes, as it is incorrect. Also the type of the literal has nothing to do with the result in this specific case.