# integer promotion in c

Tags: c, integer-overflow, integer-promotion

**Let say I have a 32-bit machine.**

I know during *integer promotion* the expressions are converted to:

- `int` if all values of the original type can be represented in int
- `unsigned` otherwise

Could you please explain what will happen for the following expression? and In general, how ranking works here?

First snippet:

```
int16_t  x, pt;
int32_t  speed;
uint16_t length;
x = (speed*pt)/length;
```

Second one:

```
x = pt + length;
```

#EDIT:

I found the following link that has described the issue very clearly:
[Implicit type conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17312545/type-conversion-unsigned-to-signed-int-char/17312930#17312930).

Concretely, read the answer of **Lundin**, very helpful!

Comment: What are `si16`, `si32`, and `u16`?

Comment: Question is impossible answer without knowing `sizeof(int)` relative to `sizeof(si16)` and others.

Comment: "Let say i have 32 bit machine." is not at all relevant. We need to know the details of your `int`.

Comment: @ David Bowling , si16 means signed short (size 16 bit) , si32 bit means signed int (size 32 bit) and u16 means unsigned short (size 16)

Comment: why `si16` but `u16`, not `ui16`?

Comment: I hope the info on this page can help you: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_type_casting.htm

Comment: Why are you using, e.g., `si32`? This is not at all clear. Is this a fixed-width type, as your comment suggests: `int32_t`, or is this an `int`, as your comment suggests? Same question for the other unspecified `typedef`s.

Comment: please consider si32, simply, as label of signed int

Comment: @Jimmy That's a bad tutorial, the author got the terms all wrong, mixing up casts and conversions. And he seems to be living in the year 1990, for example all his examples invoke undefined behavior since the OS might use the return value of main(). Don't recommend newbies to read such old crap please.

Answer (score 10):

The integer promotion rule, correctly cited C11 6.3.1.1:

> If an `int` can represent all values of the original type (as restricted
> by the width, for a bit-field), the value is converted to an `int`;
> otherwise, it is converted to an `unsigned int`. These are called the
> integer promotions. All other types are unchanged by the integer
> promotions.

Where "otherwise, it is converted to an unsigned int" is in practice only used in one particular special case, namely where the smaller integer type `unsigned short` has the same size as `unsigned int`. In that case it will remain unsigned.

Apart from that special case, all small integer types will always get promoted to (signed) `int` regardless of their signedness.

---

Assuming 32 bit `int`, then:

```
 x = (speed*pt)/length;
```

`speed` is signed 32, it will not get promoted. `pt` will get integer promoted to `int` (signed 32). The result of `speed*pt` will have type `int`.

`length` will get integer promoted to `int`. The division will get carried out with operands of type `int` and the resulting type will be `int`.

The result will get converted to signed 16 as it is assigned to `x` (lvalue conversion during assignment).

`x =  pt + length;` is similar, here both operands of + will get promoted to `int` before addition and the result will afterwards get converted to signed 16.

For details see [Implicit type promotion rules](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46073295/584518).

Comment: could you please explain the line : "All other types are unchanged by the integer promotions."

Comment: @Monir With some more context, it means that all types that aren't of the "small integer types" aren't affected by the rule. The small integer types are: bool, char, short (and their stdint.h equivalents).

Comment: It is allowed to apply an operator without converting it first to int provided you can prove it will not overflow.

Comment: @alinsoar Compilers may optimize such expressions but they are indeed not allowed to optimize out side effects caused by promotion, including implicit change of signedness.

Answer (score 2):

The integer promotion rules are defined in [6.3.1.8 Usual arithmetic conversions](http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/6.3.1.8.html).

```
1.  int16_t  x, pt;
    int32_t  speed;
    uint16_t length;
    x = (speed*pt)/length;

2. x =  pt + length;
```

Ranking means effectively the number of bits from the type as defined by CAM in `limits.h`.  The standards imposes for the types of lower rank in CAM to correspond types of lower rank in implementation.

For your code,

```
speed * pt
```

is multiplication between int32_t and int16_t, which means, it is transformed in

```
speed * (int16_t => int32_t) pt
```

and the result `tmp1` will be `int32_t`.

Next, it will continue

```
tmp1_int32 / length
```

Length will be converted from `uint16_t` to `int32_t`, so it will compute `tmp2` so:

```
tmp1_int32 / (uint16_t => int32_t) length
```

and the result `tmp2` will be of type `int32_t`.

Next it will evaluate an assignment expression, left side of 16 bits and the right side of 32, so it will cut the result so:

```
x = (int32_t => int16_t) tmp2_int32
```

Your second case will be evaluated as

```
x = (int32_t => int16_t) ( (int16_t => int32_t) pt + (uint16_t => int32_t) length )
```

In case an operator has both operands with rank smaller than the rank of int, the CAM allows to add both types if the operation does not overflow and then to convert the result to integer.

In other words, it is possible to covert INT16+INT16 either in

```
 INT16+INT16
```

or in

```
 (int32_t => int16_t) ((int16_t => int32_t) INT16 + (int16_t => int32_t) INT16)
```

provided the addition can be done without overflow.

Comment: "Ranking", that is _conversion rank_, is formally specified in 6.3.1.1.

Comment: What is "CAM" supposed to mean?

Comment: c abstract machine

Comment: I was talking about integer promotions concerning my reference, not about ranking.

Comment: to be more precise, CAM means the abstract semantics defined by the standard.

Comment: I don't see what the abstract machine has to do with limits.h. And please do not invent more three-letter abbreviations... "CAM" is neither a formal nor a de facto standard term.

Comment: Regarding optimizations, the compiler is actually not always allowed to do optimizations like described, not only because of overflows, but also because integer promotion might cause implicit change of signedness and other such nasty things that may not get optimized away, or the meaning of the program would be changed.

Comment: For example `unsigned char a = 1; unsigned char b = 2; if(a - b < 0) puts("< 0");` must result in "< 0" getting printed even though there are no overflows present. The compiler is not allowed to skip the unintended side effect caused by the promotion - it is not allowed to evaluate the expression as unsigned char type which would have given the result 255.

Comment: @Lundin  I am sorry to tell you that you are wrong.  Look more over the C standard.

Comment: In limits.h are defined the minimum number of bits for each type and this is in direct correlation with the rank of each type (apart from int, that is a special case)

Comment: All the C standard says in terms of the abstract machine is that the compiler is allowed to optimize code if it can deduct that result will be the same as when no optimizations were present. See the above code example - optimizations are required to give a negative value, even if the actual calculation of `a - b` is carried out on a 8 bit type. For the same reason as `sizeof(a - b)` must give result 4 on a 32 bit machine.

Comment: As already mentioned, rank is specified by 6.3.1.1 and not by limits.h or anything else: `The rank of long long int shall be greater than the rank of long int, which shall be greater than the rank of int, which shall be greater than the rank of short int, which shall be greater than the rank of signed char.`

Comment: I know where the rank is.  I said that it is in correlation with limits.h.  This is my observation and you can check it.

Comment: In limits.h, 5.2.4.2.1, SHRT_MIN and SHRT_MAX have the very same value as INT_MIN and INT_MAX. Yet `int` always have greater conversion rank than `short`.

Comment: Did you read what I said above ? ``In limits.h are defined the minimum number of bits for each type and this is in direct correlation with the rank of each type (apart from int, that is a special case)``

Comment: Perhaps  you could quote the standard where exactly "the minimum number of bits" are specified then? Since `CHAR_BITS` is the only such constant specified by the standard.

Comment: It provides minimum limits and it specifies that it's used the base 2 (one of 3 possible encodings in base 2 are allowed) so one can deduce.

Comment: @Lundin Some compilers for embedded system might have an option to compile more optimal code if user wants to do so. Also, it is not a good idea to have code that rely on integer promotion... as it somehow hide the intent.

Comment: @Phil1970 Yes absolutely, but they are not allowed to optimize any side effects caused by implicit promotion, such as change of signedness, since those side effects could be intentional. Indeed it is a horrible idea to write code that relies on implicit promotion, but the compiler can't tell if such reliance is intentional or accidental.