# Shouldn't the difference of two uint16_t types also be a uint16_t?

Tags: c, language-lawyer

Why are these two versions of code different? I had been under the impression that unsigned integer overflow is well-defined in C and that if you have `uint16_t a,b` then `a-b` has a result type of `uint16_t`.

```
#include <stdint.h>

uint32_t frobnicate1(uint32_t prevsum, uint16_t command, uint16_t response)
{
    uint32_t error = command-response;
    return prevsum + error; 
}

uint32_t zoop1()
{
    return frobnicate1(0, 30001, 30002);
}

uint32_t frobnicate2(uint32_t prevsum, uint16_t command, uint16_t response)
{
    uint16_t error = command-response;
    return prevsum + error; 
}

uint32_t zoop2()
{
    return frobnicate2(0, 30001, 30002);
}
```

But `zoop1()` returns -1 (not expected!!!) whereas `zoop2()` returns 65535 (expected).

When I see `command-response` and the result is -1 modulo 65536 = 65535, and is supposed to have type `uint16_t`, I'm wondering why the compiler is allows to promote 65535 to -1 when going to `uint32_t`.

(Tried on godbolt.org with x86-64 gcc and clang `-O2 -Wall`)

Comment: Only if `sizeof(unsigned int) == sizeof(uint16_t)`.  Otherwise integer promotions occur before the difference is calculated, so the result is `int`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44455248/integer-promotion-in-c

Comment: @HansPassant related but different question.

Comment: I'm willing to accept a dupehammer verdict but not with that redirection. The best original to cite is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not necessarily.

C has no arithmetic operations on integer types narrower than `int` and `unsigned int`. If `uint16_t` is narrower than `unsigned int` (as it is in most implementations), then any operands of type `uint16_t` are promoted to `int` before an operation is applied.

`uint16_t` is likely to be defined as `unsigned short`; the same thing happens with operands of type `unsigned short`, which are typically promoted to `int`.

Comment: "C has no arithmetic operations on integer types narrower " -- what? where is that in the standard? I'm looking at N1256 https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf -- currently looking at 6.3.1.8 usual arithmetic conversions

Comment: "Otherwise, the integer promotions are performed on both operands. Then the
following rules are applied to the promoted operands:
If both operands have the same type, then no further conversion is needed"

Comment: sigh, it's clarified in a footnote: "EXAMPLE 2 In executing the fragment
char c1, c2;
/* ... */
c1 = c1 + c2;
the ‘‘integer promotions’’ require that the abstract machine promote the value of each variable to int size
and then add the two ints and truncate the sum. Provided the addition of two chars can be done without
overflow, or with overflow wrapping silently to produce the correct result, the actual execution need only
produce the same result, possibly omitting the promotions."