# Visual Studio not returning correct C float values

Tags: c, floating-point, return-value, visual-studio-2019

I am doing some fairly simple math in visual studio 2019 with C, but floats are returning with incorrect values. While debugging I simplified the example down to just a quick return, but something is still off because there's no math included in my example. Is there something missing from my environment?

NOTE: I can return integers with no problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
   float e = simple_float();
   printf("after return : %.2f\n", e);

   return 0;
}

float simple_float() {
    float a = 5.63129;
    printf("before return : %.2f\n", a);
    return 5.63129;
}
```

But the output is displaying as such:

[image]

Comment: Declare the function *before* you use it. Your compiler may assume the return type is `int` and then all sorts of problems emerge.

Comment: What do you mean "Visual Basic with C"?? This is C code. It's far from clear how Visual Basic factors in. Do you mean Visual Studio?

Comment: MSVC compiler gives *five* warnings for this short code. Please treat them as errors.

Comment: Two of those warnings concern truncating `double` values to `float`. Unless you have a compelling reason to use `float`, **always** use `double`. If your teacher hasn't yet heard of `double` then move to another school.

Comment: @user3121023 smh, that was it. I'm embarrassed to make such a simple mistake, I would remove it but you deserve the credit for you solution. Can you please post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @WeatherVane If `double` is so great, why isn't there… I mean why isn't everyone using `long double`?
Seriously, switching to `double` is not the topic of this question.

Comment: @PascalCuoq `long double` is not fully supported. Seriously.  But `double` is, except for restrictive environments, for example due to lack of memory, or execution speed when there is no co-processor, when `float` is then preferable. My swipe was actually about teachers who are still teaching from 20th century resources.

Comment: @WeatherVane Ah, so it's vitally important to use `double` instead of `float` and you should change schools over it, but `long double`, which one might imagine is even better because it is to `double` what `double` is to `float`, is not worth being fully supported in a, what, thirty-years-old compiler? Got it!

Comment: @PascalCuoq `double` is no strain on most modern systems. I am not the only one with this opinion, please see [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61709217/how-to-see-the-size-of-the-incoming-floating-point-number#comment109153655_61709217). Perhaps you think that was bad advice and that we should still be using `float` even encouraging it. Why? *Why* don't you think we should use `double`, apart from trolling?

Comment: @WeatherVane 80-bit `long double` has been no strain on most modern systems, specifically on x86 and x86-64 since the 486 was launched in 1989, so I don't understand why you insist on recommending low-precision `double`. But for the record, since apparently this is not clear yet, I think that your comment is off-topic in addition to claiming as general principle a fact that doesn't apply everywhere. It has the same value as a comment on the use of spaces instead of tabs. It's irrelevant to the question being asked, and whatever you think is better is not even objectively better.

Comment: @PascalCuoq I did not say `double` is better. The C compiler considers `42` is the `int` type, and `4.2` is the `double` type. If you code `float f = 4.2;` the compiler will say the value may be truncated. C18 says *"§ 6.4.4.2 Para 4 An unsuffixed floating constant has type double."* At times you may want to use `long long int` or `long double` but for general use it makes practical sense to work with the types favoured by the standard and the by compiler writers. But hang on – I seem to recall you work with `float` not with the `long double` you now advocate. If so I understand your concern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will not even compile if you try gcc/clang. I'm surprised visual C allows this. Does it not have any stricter settings ?

By default, C assumes the return type of any function as ‘int’. So, declare the function prior, which is good practice anyway. Fyi, errors from a C99 compliant compiler:

```
foo.c:6:14: warning: implicit declaration of function 'simple_float' is invalid in
      C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   float e = simple_float();
             ^
foo.c:12:7: error: conflicting types for 'simple_float'
float simple_float() {
      ^
foo.c:6:14: note: previous implicit declaration is here
   float e = simple_float();
             ^
1 warning and 1 error generated.
```

Comment: It's been a long time since I've touched C, but you bring up a good point. When I declared the function prior, it fixed it (*my mistake*) but I am definitely interested in how this built successfully and VS permitted this.

Comment: similar answer here for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12373538/warning-return-type-defaults-to-int-wreturn-type

Comment: Some more digging, C89 and C90 allowed this as a "feature". Nowadays, this is considered bad practice (as of C99).

Comment: "I'm surprised visual C allows this." --> VC tends to follow C89 - quite lenient.

Answer (score 1):

The Problem with your code is that you are not declaring the function before using it. In that case, the compiler assumes the return type int:

```
#include <stdio.h>

float foo(void);

int main(void) {
  printf("With known prototype : %.2f\n", foo());
  printf("Without known prototype : %.2f\n", bar());
  return 0;
}

float foo() {
  return 5.63129f;
}

float bar() {
  return 5.63129f;
}
```

will output `5.63` in the first line and `0.00` on my machine, compiled with vc. But that seems to depend on the machine.

Compiling this on gcc will result in an error.

Nearly **every** modern compiler warns about this when compiling and most of them throw an error because the type-check will find a conflict in the actual definition.

I just tried out different compilers, and indeed, there are some compilers that don't regard this as an error. E.g. vc and sdcc just warn the user, but they will generate an output that will result in undefined behaviour.